# command npm install is not working and showing errors

Tags: angular, npm-install

When entered npm install the following errors appeared

Errors displayed in terminal

i want to set up my angular project but fail miserably !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAvlG.png)

Comment: try changing folder location out of C folder and try again

Comment: Angular installer is trying to install web-animation-js, which is not an NPM module but rather module hosted on GIT. If you do not have GIT installed, try to install it and then try again. Here is an open issue about this module: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14826

Comment: Please don't use an image but copy/paste the error into your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Try with

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and after that do `npm install`

If above not work then try with below solution

Update the version of core-js to version above 3.

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

and after that do `npm install`